# Building nodejs app in jenkins using 'npx microbundle' command gettig error

Tags: node.js, jenkins

[Pipeline] sh

- npx microbundle-crl build --target web --external none --format umd --name ReferralSdk --css inline
  npx: installed 513 in 29.549s
  [31m[1mError: 'createLogger' is not exported by node_modules/redux-logger/dist/redux-logger.js, imported by src/store/ConfigStore.js[39m[22m

at /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/referral-sdk-js_jenkins-deploy/src/store/ConfigStore.js:2:9

[2m1: import { applyMiddleware, compose, createStore } from "redux";
2: import { createLogger } from 'redux-logger'
^
3: import reducers from "../redux";
4: import thunk from "redux-thunk";[22m

Here is the configStore.js file

```
import { applyMiddleware, compose, createStore } from "redux";
import { createLogger } from 'redux-logger'
import reducers from "../redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
const middleware = [createLogger(),thunk]
const ConfigStore = () => {
    let store = null; 
    store = createStore(reducers,{},compose(applyMiddleware(...middleware)))
    return store
}
export default ConfigStore()
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "infinite-react-carousel": "^1.2.11",
    "nuka-carousel": "^4.6.6",
    "react": "^16.13.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.0",
    "react-items-carousel": "^2.8.0",
    "react-meta-tags": "^0.7.4",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the source code for `src/store/ConfigStore.js`

Answer (score 0):

Hi there and welcome,

So the error comes from line 2 for the ReactJs source code at `src/store/ConfigStore.js`

The error is coming from an import statement where you are trying to import `createLogger` from the `redux-logger` package, and it can't find that function.

This is the line here:

```js
import {createLogger} from 'redux-logger';
```

It cannot find createLogger or it's not exported.

This seems to be an error with the package, where you will find some solutions: https://github.com/LogRocket/redux-logger/issues/233

Some possible solutions will be to:

- upgrade or downgrade the package, by going to `package.json` and finding the dependency `react-logger` and finding an appropriate version that exports this function correctly
- Depending on what bundler you are using (e.g. webpack or rollup) perhaps try some of the solutions from the issue e.g.

```js
import * as logger from 'redux-logger';

logger.__moduleExports.createLogger;
```

- if you are using typescript (it doesnt look like it) remember to include the @types e.g. `npm i @types/redux-logger`